# Bitbucket squash commits on a branch

Tags: bitbucket

I have a load of commits, on a bitbucket branch where I was experimenting on the code. I want to squash all those into just one commit, without squashing all the other commits.
Does this call for a rebase.

Bit confused on what a rebase is.

Comment: see my answer please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/70306667#70306667

Comment: Hi thanks it sort of confused me. I did git rebase -i qa,  qa being the Branch I want to squash commits  on. But all I got was a v1 editor. Do I need to then write a script. Is thee a way to do it by the bitbucket console.

Answer (score 1):

yep you will get a console to edit the commits: like this:

`git rebase -i qa` then press keyboard 'i' to edit

you will see like this:

```
pick etc1
pick etc2
pick etc2
```

replace the word pick with 'f' and press esc y :wq

```
pick etc1 //this commit will the one commit
**f** etc2
**f** etc2
```

and press this command

```
git push origin +head
```

Comment: I dont get I got the following I just got a list of instructions noop

# Rebase f20a064..f20a064 onto f20a064 (1 command)
#

Comment: If I do this git reset --hard-10 , will this remove the last 10 commits on QA. That will work for me.